# No puedo guardar el texto dentro de una función en CSV de python

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero guardar el texto que puse en la caja de texto de una función llamada def libro():, pero al momento de darle en el botón guardar para guardar el texto de la función def libro():, si me aparece el archivo de texto, pero no me aparece el texto de las variables. Ya intente cambiando el csvwriter.writerow(libro_nombre) a csvwriter.writerows(libro_nombre) y csvwriter(libro_nombre), ,no me funciono, aquí dejo el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

biblioteca = tk.Tk()
biblioteca.config(width=300, height=270)
biblioteca.title("Biblioteca")
texto_principal = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Colocar Nuevo Libro")
texto_principal.place(x=70, y=20)

texto = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de libro: ")
texto.place(x=10, y=50)
entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.place(x=140, y=50)
texto1 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de editorial: ")
texto1.place(x=10, y=80)
entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(x=140, y=80)
texto2 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre del autor: ")
texto2.place(x=10, y=110)
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(x=140, y=110)
texto3 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Número de paginas: ")
texto3.place(x=10, y=140)
entry3 = ttk.Entry()
entry3.place(x=140, y=140)

def libro():
  libro_nombre = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Libro: " + entry.get())
  libro_nombre.place(x=120, y=200)
  libro_editorial = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Editorial: " + entry1.get())
  libro_editorial.place(x=120, y=215)
  libro_autor = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Autor: " + entry2.get())
  libro_autor.place(x=120, y=230)
  libro_paginas = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nº de Paginas: " + entry3.get())
  libro_paginas.place(x=120, y=245)

  guardado = "libro1.txt"
  with open(guardado, 'w') as csvfile:
      csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
      csvwriter.writerow(libro_nombre)
      csvwriter.writerow(libro_editorial)      
      csvwriter.writerow(libro_autor) 
      csvwriter.writerow(libro_paginas)
 
boton = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Guardar", command = libro)
boton.place(x=140, y=170)

biblioteca.mainloop()
```

Aquí dejo como me recopila y me sale el archivo texto, pero no me guarda el texto de la variable que puse para guardar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El primer problema es que estás intentando utilizar las variables de las etiquetas directamente en `writerow` pero lo que necesitas es el texto de las etiquetas, no la etiqueta en sí.

Para obtener el texto de la etiqueta utilizamos `.cget('text')` por ejemplo:

```
csvwriter.writerow(libro_nombre.cget('text'))
```

Ahora, un segundo problema es que `writerow` espera una secuencia (Por ejemplo una lista) de lo contrario va a escribir una coma después de cada letra, por ejemplo al ingresar `aa` en Libro escribiría así:

```
L,i,b,r,o,:, ,a,a
```

Por lo que hay que pasar una lista como argumento "encerrando" el texto de la etiqueta entre corchetes `[]`:

```
csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')])
```

Un posible tercer problema es que si utilizas `with open(guardado, 'w') as csvfile:` el archivo siempre se va a sobreescribir, supongo que deseas guardar varios libros en el mismo archivo por lo que puedes utilizar `a` (Append) en lugar de `w` (Write)

```
with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

biblioteca = tk.Tk()
biblioteca.config(width=300, height=270)
biblioteca.title("Biblioteca")
texto_principal = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Colocar Nuevo Libro")
texto_principal.place(x=70, y=20)

texto = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de libro: ")
texto.place(x=10, y=50)
entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.place(x=140, y=50)
texto1 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de editorial: ")
texto1.place(x=10, y=80)
entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(x=140, y=80)
texto2 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre del autor: ")
texto2.place(x=10, y=110)
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(x=140, y=110)
texto3 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Número de paginas: ")
texto3.place(x=10, y=140)
entry3 = ttk.Entry()
entry3.place(x=140, y=140)

def libro():
    libro_nombre = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Libro: " + entry.get())
    libro_nombre.place(x=120, y=200)
    libro_editorial = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Editorial: " + entry1.get())
    libro_editorial.place(x=120, y=215)
    libro_autor = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Autor: " + entry2.get())
    libro_autor.place(x=120, y=230)
    libro_paginas = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nº de Paginas: " + entry3.get())
    libro_paginas.place(x=120, y=245)
    

    guardado = "libro1.txt"
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_nombre.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_editorial.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_autor.cget('text')])
        csvwriter.writerow([libro_paginas.cget('text')])

boton = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Guardar", command = libro)
boton.place(x=140, y=170)

biblioteca.mainloop()
```